# Write a class accepting any kind of Callable object with constraints

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

I'm working on a small project, trying to create a system in which I have several instances of a class `Rule`, each performing an action before passing the control to the next rule according to the result of the action. The action can be anything, can accept any number of parameters or none, but always returns a `Message` (enum). I would like to be able to write the action in the more generic way possible : as a function, a lambda, pointer to function, etc. so that I'm not bound to a specific syntax

As of now, here is what the code looks like

```
#include <concepts>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

enum Message {
    success,
    failure,
    nothing
};

class BaseRule {};

template <typename F, typename ...Args> requires std::invocable<F, Args...>
class Rule: public BaseRule {
private:
    std::map<Message, BaseRule*> successors;    //a feature allowing to chain rules, unused at this moment
    template <typename... Ts> struct undef;     // for testing purposes only

public:
    F action;

    Rule(F _action) : action(_action) {};
    void addSuccessor(const Message, BaseRule*);
    void removeSuccessor(const Message);

    template <typename... ExecuteArgs>
    void execute(ExecuteArgs&&... args) {
        //execute the action, and call the next rule's action according to the Message returned

    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<F, ExecuteArgs...>)
        std::invoke(action, std::forward<ExecuteArgs>(args)...);
    else
        undef<F, ExecuteArgs...> _; // for testing purposes, expected to fail and give me the types of F and ExecuteArgs in the error message
    };

};

class App {
private:
    std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::function<void()>> boundActions;

public:
    template <typename F, typename ...Args> requires std::invocable<F, Args...>
    void bindInput(const unsigned int _key, BaseRule* _rule, Args... _args) {
        auto callable = [_rule, _args...]() {
            static_cast<Rule<F, Args...>*>(_rule)->execute(_args...);
        };
        boundActions[_key] = callable;
    };

    template <typename F, typename ...Args> requires std::invocable<F, Args...>
    void launch(Rule<F> _startingPoint, Args... args) {
        _startingPoint.execute(args...);
        loop();
    };

    void loop() {
        while (!quit) {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
                if (downKeys[i]) {
                    auto it = boundActions.find(i);
                    if (it != boundActions.end())
                        it->second();   // Invoke the stored callable object
                }
            }
        }
    };
};

int main() {
    App app = App();

    //app is captured in the lamba to perform some logic
    Rule init = Rule([&app]() -> Message {
        std::cout << "Initialization" << std::endl;
        return nothing;
    });

    //This fails
    Rule mark = Rule([&app](const unsigned int _target) -> Message {
        std::cout << "Mark" << std::endl;
        return success;
    });

    app.bindInput<decltype(init.action)>(32, &init);
    app.bindInput<decltype(mark.action)>(65, &mark, 0); //Thus, this also fails
    app.bindInput<decltype(mark.action)>(90, &mark, 1); //Same

    app.launch(&init);

    return 0;
}
```

This code let me create the rule `init`, but fails to instantiate the rule `mark`, with several errors relating to template argument deduction, chiefly C2748 `'Rule<F> Rule(Rule<F>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'Rule<F>' from 'main::<lambda_2>'` on `mark` Rule instantiation (other errors come from the failure to instantiate `mark`).
I've also tried to replace the lambda by a function, but the errors remained. Trying with `Rule<decltype(markF)> mark = Rule<decltype(markF)>(markF);` (`markF` being a function with the same behaviour as the previous lambda used to instantiate `mark`) added a new C7602 error the associated constraints are not satisfied. But using a function with no parameters work just fine.

As a side note, I've noticed another problem (it will have its own question if resolving the current issue doesn't solve it already). At `if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<F, ExecuteArgs...>)`, an error C2100 illegal indirection appears

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where are all the `#include`s? Post complete errors. Also one question per post.

Comment: @user12002570 : I've corrected my post. I only have one question, I've said the side note would be the subject of a separate question, but I think it may be useful for the current issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never deduce `Args...` to be anything other than an empty pack, because there is nothing specifying it from `F`. In general, there are multiple possible `Args...` such that `std::invocable<F, Args...>` is true.

The simplest fix is to remove `Args...` from the template parameters of `Rule`.

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e73be476e1006c8)

Comment: It worked, thanks for your answer !
Why is it that you can never deduce `Args...` to be something other than an pack? Could you epxlain it?

Comment: @MetaZenithian There's nothing to deduce it from